# What happens to the character buffer when my std::string is resized?

Tags: c++, string, memory, memory-management

**Background:**

In an effort to get better acquainted with memory management in C++, I recently decided to write my own memory management library.

Currently, this library doesn't consist of much other than a basic pool allocator, the entirety of which is small enough to inline below:

```
PoolAllocator::PoolAllocator (const AllocatorConfig& config)
{
    this->nextAddress = 0;
    this->size = config.AllocatorSize;
    this->memoryArray = new byte[this->size];
}

PoolAllocator::~PoolAllocator ()
{
    delete[] this->memoryArray;
}

void * PoolAllocator::Allocate (size_t size)
{
    void* pointer = &(this->memoryArray[this->nextAddress]);
    this->nextAddress += (unsigned long)size;
    return pointer;
}

void PoolAllocator::Delete (void * object)
{
    this->nextAddress -= sizeof (object);
}
```

I then use the allocator by replacing the global new to use the allocator (if it exists, otherwise it just uses malloc, which is what is called when the allocator itself is constructed).

**The problem:**

In testing this class, I wrote a simple application to allocate a std::string object, shown below:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "PoolAllocator.hpp"
#include "AllocatorConfig.hpp"

PoolAllocator *allocator;

int main (int numArgs, char *args[]) 
{
    AllocatorConfig config = AllocatorConfig ();
    config.AllocatorSize = 2048;
    allocator = new PoolAllocator (config);

    std::string *s = new std::string();

    std::cout << "String object size: " << sizeof (*s) << std::endl;

    *s = "test";
    char *charBuffer = &((*s)[0]);

    std::cout << "First allocate offset: " << (int)((int)&((*s)[0]) - (int)s) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Original cstring: " << charBuffer << std::endl;

    *s = "thisIsALongStringToTestTheAddress";

    std::cout << "Second allocate offset: " << (int)((int)&((*s)[0]) - (int)s) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Original cstring: " << charBuffer << std::endl;

    delete allocator;
}

void * operator new(size_t size) 
{
    if (allocator)
    {
        return allocator->Allocate(size);
    }
    else 
    {
        return malloc (size);
    }
}
```

The output was as follows:

```
String object size: 28
First allocate offset: 4
Original cstring: test
Second allocate offset: 36
Original cstring: ,ÀH
```

This seemed fairly reasonable at first, given that the string primitive pointed to internally by the std::string needs to be contiguous, and std::string really has no way of knowing that it can simply expand into the adjacent contiguous space.

**HOWEVER**

When replacing both global `delete` and `delete[]` and attaching the debugger, I never saw any evidence that either was called.  I also tried to break on `free`, but that didn't work either, so...

**The Question:**

What is std::string doing with that memory?  I would have assumed it would call `delete[]` so my allocator could reclaim it, but as far as I can tell it's not releasing it at all.  Is it just spraying the heap in that spot and holding on to it until it dies, or is there something else going on here that I'm missing?

Comment: `*s = "test";` -- If you're expecting that memory was allocated, maybe not due to *short string optimization*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is *short string optimization* where the string object stores very small strings directly in its own allocation, so there is nothing to deallocate on reassignment.

See [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91df975cf4a057fe), where we have a similar test and these results:

```
declaration
assignment of 'test'
assignment of 'thisIsALongStringToTestTheAddress'
allocate(34) = 0xb7ac30
assignment of 'thisIsALongStringToTestTheAddressthisIsALongStringToTestTheAddressthisIsALongStringToTestTheAddressthisIsALongStringToTestTheAddress'
allocate(133) = 0xb7ac60
deallocate(0xb7ac30, 34)
scope end
deallocate(0xb7ac60, 133)
```

To interpret this:

- When assigning `"test"` there is no allocation.
- When assigning a longer string, there is an allocation.
- When assigning a much longer string to force a reallocation, there is another allocation (for the new content) followed by the deallocation (of the old content), which is the order we would generally expect (so that if the allocation fails, we can abort the operation without destroying the old data).
- Finally, we see a deallocation when the string is destroyed.

---

But wait, why don't you see any deallocation for the longer string that you assigned?  Well, **you never `delete s;`** and so your program terminates with a leaked allocation that the operating system will clean up itself.  Add `delete s;` prior to `delete allocator;` and you should see the allocation freed in your `operator delete`.

---

Source code of the test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class AllocatorProxy
{
private:
    Allocator proxy;

public:
    using pointer = typename Allocator::pointer;
    using const_pointer = typename Allocator::const_pointer;
    using value_type = typename Allocator::value_type;
    using size_type = typename Allocator::size_type;
    using difference_type = typename Allocator::difference_type;

    pointer allocate(size_type n)
    {
        pointer p = proxy.allocate(n);

        std::cout << "allocate(" << n << ") = " << static_cast<void *>(p) << '\n';

        return p;
    }

    pointer allocate(size_type n, void const *l)
    {
        pointer p = proxy.allocate(n, l);

        std::cout << "allocate(" << n << ", " << l << ") = " << static_cast<void *>(p) << '\n';

        return p;
    }

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n) noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "deallocate(" << static_cast<void *>(p) << ", " << n << ")\n";

        proxy.deallocate(p, n);
    }

    size_type max_size()
    {
        return proxy.max_size();
    }
};

using astring = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, AllocatorProxy<char>>;

int main() {
    std::cout << "declaration\n";
    astring str;

    std::cout << "assignment of 'test'\n";
    str.assign("test");

    std::cout << "assignment of 'thisIsALongStringToTestTheAddress'\n";
    str.assign("thisIsALongStringToTestTheAddress");

    std::cout << "assignment of 'thisIsALongStringToTestTheAddressthisIsALongStringToTestTheAddressthisIsALongStringToTestTheAddressthisIsALongStringToTestTheAddress'\n";
    str.assign("thisIsALongStringToTestTheAddressthisIsALongStringToTestTheAddressthisIsALongStringToTestTheAddressthisIsALongStringToTestTheAddress");

    std::cout << "scope end\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting!  Thanks for the in-depth response.  I think part of what confused me was that the short string buffer was part of a separate allocation, rather than as part of the initial new.

Comment: The short string *is* part of the initial string allocation, though. That's the point!

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I went back and took a peak at the VS 2017 implementation of std::string and debugged once more, and what I thought was a separate allocation for the area the short string would be stored was actually an object of type _Container_proxy, the purpose of which I haven't quite yet discerned.  The string literal on the other hand was within the std::string object's memory, only 4 bytes from the start.